# Sumar promedios en Power BI

Tags: powerbi, microsoft

En la tabla que se muestra a continuación es una tabla normal, donde la columna FTE es una medida (o measure) que promedia una serie de valores agrupados por usuarios (las filas que están censuradas).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente el valor que está subrayado en rojo muestra el promedio de todos los FTE de todos esos usuarios mostrados.

¿Hay manera de que exista una medida (o measure) que muestre en las filas normales el promedio de FTE de cada usuario, pero que en los grupos totales muestre la sumatoria de esos promedios mostrados? Para el ejemplo de la imagen el valor sería 7,6.

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto te servirá, al menos para esta tabla. En resumen, realiza la media del valor `Tabla[Campo]` para todas las áreas, y si el valor mostrado (como el total) no dispone de área, entonces realiza la suma de las medias.

```
FTE Total = 
    var FTE= AVERAGE(Tabla[Campo]) 
RETURN 
    IF (HASONEVALUE(Tabla[Area]); FTE; SUMX(VALUES(Tabla[Area]); FTE))
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!